# Adding a numpy array with another numpy array only at selected indeces

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to add certain elements in an array to another array selectively using indeces. Is this achievable without using an if statement? For instance:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
y = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
idx = np.array([1, 3])

res = np.add(x,y[idx])

print res
```

How would you get a desired result of `[1., 3., 3., 5., 5.]` without using an if statement?

Comment: You can use the the optional `where` argument for exactly this [np.add](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)

Comment: @the_cheff How would you set up the arguments if you were to use `where`?

Comment: `x[idx] += y[idx]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

broadcasting takes into acount both sides of the assignment

```
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
y = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
idx = np.array([1, 3])

x[idx] += y[idx]

x
Out[3]: array([1., 3., 3., 5., 5.])
```